# In JavaFX 8, when creating a single TableView row containing a DatePicker as a cell, the DatePickers are rendered even in nonexistent table rows

Tags: java, datepicker, tableview, javafx-8

I have this JavaFX 8 GUI:
[image: My GUI]

The column "Expires" contains [DatePicker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) components as cells. As you can see, the component in question is rendered in all visible rows, even if they are not yet created in the table.

My question is: *how can I render the DatePicker cells only in rows that are created?*

Before posting this one, I googled a lot yet not to avail; I just don't see anything of relevance.

My so called cell factory is:

```
tableColumnExpirationDate.setCellFactory(
    new ExpirationDatePickerCellFactory(tableView.getItems()));
```

where

```
public class ExpirationDatePickerCellFactory 
        implements Callback<TableColumn<Bill, Date>, 
                            TableCell<Bill, Date>> {
    @Override
    public DatePickerCell call(TableColumn<Bill, Date> column) {
        return new DatePickerCell(billList);
    }
}
```

once again, where

`DatePickerCell` is from [this blog](http://physalix.com/javafx8-render-a-datepicker-cell-in-a-tableview/).

Comment: The quality of the `DatePickerCell`'s code is pretty miserable. E.g. there are type parameters for the class, but they are never used, in the constructor a field that has not been initialized is checked for `null`. Also the class allows you to pass your own `DatePicker`. But does it prepare the class the same way it prepares the instance it creates in the constructor? Nope. Does it unregister the listeners from the old datepicker so that it could safely be reused somewhere else? Nope. Override `startEdit` just to call the super method. Requesting focus for every datepicker...

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty horrible all round. I could only read a couple of methods before I gave up keeping track of what was wrong. Probably easier just to roll your own implementation.

Comment: @James_D Fair enough. In my code, I didn't do anything unusual so I thought it would make sense to ask here, since it is possible other Java FX developers may face that problem sooner or later.

Comment: @coderodde I meant the code in the blog post, not your code (in case that's not clear). You could try omitting the call to `setGraphic(...)` in the `DatePickerCell` constructor, but a lot of the code in that post is just nonsense (so even if that fixes it, I would just recommend not using it).

Comment: @James_D Removing `setGraphic` hides all date pickers even in existing rows.

Comment: Try to implement your own `DatePickerCell`. Post here if you can't get it working the way you want. The flow of method calls during editing is described in the "Editing" section of the [`Cell` documentation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html).